# How do I authenticate Chrome extention backgound request to GAE site?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-chrome-extension

My extention need to automatically send some infomation to my Google App Enigne site.
The GAE site already using Google Accounts for loggin (the Users API).
Is there anyway to authenticate the extention background request after user loggin to my site?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)s**, you can set `withCredentials` to `true`, in order to include authentication related data into the request. E.g.:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
req.withCredentials = true;
req.send(null);
```

Comment: you mean the background script can use the cookie from a site? If yes, can you show me how to do that?